# FastAI V2: TabularLearner export.pkl from learn.export() is Very Large

Tags: python, fast-ai

I'm not sure if this is intended but the `export.pkl` from the `learn.export()` is about 471 MB which is somewhat prohibitive in the deployment in certain applications.

The model itself from `SaveModelCallback` is only `131 KB` and I'm only looking to use the `Learner` in order to apply the same transforms/processing (Normalization, FillMissing, Categorify).

Is there a reason this is so large? I've also confirmed

`learn.xb` =
(None, )

`learn.yb` =
(None, )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original Post: https://forums.fast.ai/t/tabularlearner-export-pkl-from-learn-export-is-very-large/81251/2

Must `pip install wwf` see https://walkwithfastai.com/tab.export

`from wwf.tab.export import *`

1. We manually save the Model in the Learner
   `torch.save(learn.model, f'{model_dir}/2_{REF}_LEARNER_MODEL.pt')`
2. We export the Tabular Object as well
   `to.export(f'{model_dir}/3_{REF}_TABULAR_OBJECT.pkl')`
3. We load the Tabular Object

```
to_new = load_pandas(f'{model_dir}/3_{REF}_TABULAR_OBJECT.pkl')
to_new = to_new.train.new(df[:20])
to_new.process()
```

4. We load the Model

```
model_2 = torch.load(f'{model_dir}/2_{REF}_LEARNER_MODEL.pt')
learn_new = TabularLearner(dls_new, model)
```

5. We do Inference

```
row, clas, probs = learn_new.predict(df.iloc[0])
row.show()
probs
```

---

The savings are substantial:

- Model: 135 kb
- Tabular Object: 6 kb

vs.

- learn.export() 417 mb